# fixing position of cells in table (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i try to fix position of cells in bootstrap with above (main row) cells but i can't

look to this image to know what i want
[image: cell's position]

and here is my code

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center" dir="rtl">
            <tr>
              <td >ردیف</td>
              <td >عنوان</td>
              <td >ویرایش</td>
              <td >حذف</td>
              
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>








    <?php
        connect();
        $news=mysql_query("select * from news");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($news)){
                $i++;
                if($i %2 == 0)
                 $bg='#9999FF';
                else
                 $bg='#fff';
                 echo '<div class="container">';
                 echo '<table class=" table table-striped table-responsive table-bordered text-center table-hover"  dir="rtl">';
                 echo '<tr >';
                
                
        echo '<td>'. $i.'</td>';        
        echo '<td>'. $row['title'].'</td>';
        echo '<td ><a href="?link=nedit&ncod='.$row['ncod'].'"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-3x " ></i></a></td>';
        echo '<td ><a href="?link=ndel&ncod='.$row['ncod'].'&npic='.$row['npic'].'"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-3x  "style="color:red" ></i> </a> </td>';
                echo '</tr> ';
                echo '</table>';
                echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>

</body>
```

and i need to fix below cells in compare with above cells

thanks

Comment: Can you post the html output as well? That way it's easier to check if the tables are rendered equally.

Comment: @Stefan that's html code, you can see rendered code in image that i embed to my question!    http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmm4Q.jpg

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i fix it myself
here is my final code

```html
<body>








    <?php
 connect();
 $news=mysql_query("select * from news");
  echo '<div class="container">';
   echo '<table class=" table table-striped table-responsive table-bordered text-center table-hover" style="white-space:nowrap; white-space-collapse:discard"  dir="rtl">';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<th>ردیف </th> ';
  echo '<th>عنوان</th> ';
  echo '<th>ویرایش </th> ';
  echo '<th>حذف</th> ';
  echo '</tr>';
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($news)){
  $i++;
  if($i %2 == 0)
   $bg='#9999FF';
  else
   $bg='#fff';
  
  
   echo '<tr >';
  
  
 echo '<td>'. $i.'</td>'; 
 echo '<td>'. $row['title'].'</td>';
 echo '<td ><a href="?link=nedit&ncod='.$row['id'].'"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-3x " ></i></a></td>';
 echo '<td ><a href="?link=ndel&ncod='.$row['ncod'].'&npic='.$row['npic'].'"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-3x  "style="color:red" ></i> </a> </td>';
  echo '</tr> ';
 
 }
 ?>
   </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening and closing a `table` and a `div` at every row, that's why;

Open the `table` once before the header, than close it once after the loop.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center" dir="rtl">
            <tr>
              <td >ردیف</td>
              <td >عنوان</td>
              <td >ویرایش</td>
              <td >حذف</td>
            </tr>

    <?php
    connect();
    $news=mysql_query("select * from news");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($news)){
        $i++;
        if($i %2 == 0)
         $bg='#9999FF';
        else
         $bg='#fff';
         echo '<tr >';
    echo '<td>'. $i.'</td>';    
    echo '<td>'. $row['title'].'</td>';
    echo '<td ><a href="?link=nedit&ncod='.$row['ncod'].'"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-3x " ></i></a></td>';
    echo '<td ><a href="?link=ndel&ncod='.$row['ncod'].'&npic='.$row['npic'].'"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-3x  "style="color:red" ></i> </a> </td>';
        echo '</tr> ';
    }?>
      </table>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: here is new result with your code
http://i.imgur.com/FqcDxIg.jpg

and here my old code
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmm4Q.jpg

not fixed yet!